# Do enqueueUniquePeriodicWork() Work Manager's method works in a Composable Function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to start a periodic task.

The problem is that I need some data to be send to the work manager and this data is only accessible when the user signs in or signs up to my app (those data are `userId` and `userScore`). I can't enqueue the worker in the Main Activity because the Main Activity doesn't recompose.

If I call the method `enqueueUniquePeriodicWork()` in a composable function do he will only start one Work and not start a Work each time the screen recompose?

So I created a ViewModel

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainActivityViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val workManager: WorkManager
) : ViewModel() {

    
}
```

with Hilt Module:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideWorkManager(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context): WorkManager =
        WorkManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wrap it in `LaunchedEffect` your `Worker` will be enqueued multiple times. What's your `ExistingPolicy`, is it `REPLACE`?

I suggest you move this to a viewmodel, or anywhere outside the UI layer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use ExistingPolicy.Keep because I don't want to replace the worker.